# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars when using trapz method

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, typeerror, numerical-integration

This is my python code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad, trapz, simps
import math

def f(x):
    return math.exp(-(x**2/2))/math.sqrt(2*math.pi)

result, error = quad(f, 0, np.inf)
print("{:f} {:g}".format(result, error))

x = np.arange(0, 99999, 0.001)

fun = f(x)

res1 = trapz(fun, x)
print(res1)
```

And am getting this error:

```
... line 6, in f
return math.exp(-(x**2/2))/math.sqrt(2*math.pi)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Why is that so?
Integration using quad method worked fine but not with trapz method

Comment: `math` functions only work with scalar values, not arrays.  Use `np.exp(x)` if `x` is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a user commented, you can only use math functions with scalar values, for arrays you have to use math functions provided in NumPy library.